# Video tag is not working in Iphone

Tags: iphone, html5-video

I have used a video tag like this

```
<video class="inview-video" poster="http://www.hillarycoe.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Pasted-image-at-2017_07_26-06_51-PM.png" muted="" controls="controls" width="300" height="150"><source src="http://www.hillarycoe.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/04-LETS-RETHINK-HS_simple.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>
```

It is working in all browser. But it not working in iphone. Like the video is auto played after view. For that

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('video.inview-video').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
        if (isInView){
            jQuery(this).css('visibility','visible').trigger('play');
        }
        else {
            jQuery(this).css('visibility','hidden').trigger('pause');
        }
    });

});
```

The video is working. But it is not working with Iphone 6. And show the play button.

Comment: Check this https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Comment: Thank you, let me try this.

Comment: I have added the "playsinline" attribute but it is not working. Actually i have used a page builder. Where i used "playsinline" in the video tag. but when i save the editor. It will disappear automatically.

Comment: Can you do some alert string in the inview function and check in iPhone. Might be inview has some issues in iPhone.

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same issue